# Unable to load '@' symbol with loadxml

Tags: c++, soap, msxml

I tried to execute the following lines

```
VARIANT_BOOL vBoolTestConnection;

vBoolTestConnection=m_spXMLDom->loadXML(bstrInput.m_str);
```

bstrInput has the following XML specifications. loadXML is returning false for the XML specified. bstrInput has '@' in the password tag. If I replace the @ symbol with anyother password characters, Load XML is working fine. Could you please help me to find the solution?

```
"<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-
 ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:SOAP-
 ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" 
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
 xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" SOAP-
 ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"><SOAP-
 ENV:Body><CheckValidUser 
 xmlns="http://systemsys"><UserName>HGDXJHSAD</UserName><Password>&</Password></CheckValidUs
er></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>"
```

Answer (score 2):

BSTR is usually UTF-16.  The XML string that you posted claims that it's using encoding UTF-8.